# How to get sum of columns of an dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with column names are titled as numbers. I need to part the excel in to two sides based on age as 'under 18' and 'above 18' so I am trying too sum up ages and create a new column as 'under 18'.
I tried doing like this but since the column is labeled with number;

```
df['under 14'] = df['Under 10'] + df['10-12'] + df['13-14'] + df['15']
```

it is giving an error but if I write the column name as 'fifteen' it gives me the total. How can I sum it up like this and keep the column name as 15?

Comment: Side note: should `under 14` really include `15` anyway?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not on pandas, but on Excel.

I believe your column name is `15` as number. So `df[15]` might work. Please check. Pandas can distinguish `'15'` as a string vs `15` as a number. You can check the column names of a dataframe by `df.columns` and quite easy you can tell. However, if you are using Excel and type `15`, Excel will try to play smart and store it as number instead of string. So this is the reason you have the error.

Solution:

1. In Excel, explicitly store a number as a string; or
2. Simply use `df[15]` instead in pandas; or
3. Before you do anything, try to normalize the column names, e.g.

   ```
   df.columns = [str(x) for x in df.columns]
   ```